# Windows 10 automatic restore on every reboot, never works

Tags: windows-10, boot

About two weeks ago, my laptop lost power while installing a graphics driver update (in GeForce experience). Since then, every time I boot my computer fails to boot and after a few attempts I get a message that automatic restore could not solve the issue.

I can workaround this issue by restoring a registry backup, but this only works for one boot. The next time I boot I'll need to do it again.

```
copy C:\windows\system32\config\regback\* C:\windows\system32\config
```

Obviously this isn't solving the issue, but instead only hiding the symptoms.

Event log doesn't show anything interesting from these reboots.

I have already tried the following things:

1. Manually update my graphics driver
2. Uninstall and then update my graphics driver
3. Running `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` [image] -- See the full log [here](https://gist.github.com/e195fe4fe9b5ca3899abe8181f4560dd). I also tried running DISM with an ISO mounted, which resulted in the same error, see that log [here](https://gist.github.com/cascer1/98a6ed6b7cf79c662b939f0f39e23857)
4. Running `sfc /scannow` [image]
5. Running Windows Update (no updates found)

I don't know what else I can try other than re-installing Windows, which is really something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: [This link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0edc3dbd-a96d-4f1b-ac49-c67216483793/dism-error-0x800f081f-and-sfc-failed-to-repair?forum=win10itprohardware) explains what to do about your DISM error 0x800f081f.

Comment: @AFH Thanks, I'm giving that a try now. Will update when I know more.

Comment: @AFH unfortunately I get the same issue when using an ISO. [log](https://gist.github.com/cascer1/98a6ed6b7cf79c662b939f0f39e23857)

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest, other than doing the copy in Safe Mode. After that, you may have to re-install with the option to preserve files, programs and settings. I have often had to do this when an upgrade fails under automatic updates, and it seems to work reasonably reliably, though I have one system that is completely unupgradable from 1607 - it will need a clean install, then re-installation of all the apps and files, plus re-installing the dual-boot Ubuntu, which I'm not prepared to do. I hope you will not be so unlucky.

Comment: Why are you trying to repair system files if the problem is a driver conflict and/or a registry issue?

Comment: @Ramhound Because I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: If you remove the driver in whatever boot configuration you can access, then reboot, are you able to boot into a normal configuration?